Problem rotating display using gnome-randr under Wayland
1 1/2 years ago I asked and found the solution under X11: Rotate second monitor on the left side using shortcut
Now I'm replacing the laptop with another one. The ubuntu is freshly installed (version 22. I had problem with 24 installer). It's using Wayland, and when I try to use the commands with xrandr, it doesn't work. I googled and read that there's problem with xrandr under Wayland. I read that Wayland has several advantages, so I want to keep it.
I'm trying to use https://gitlab.com/Oschowa/gnome-randr . When I run ./gnome-randr.py --output HDMI-1 --rotate left, it works. But after that I can't use gnome-randr to rotate anymore. It doesn't matter which direction I try to rotate it, I get this:
new monitor configuration:
logical monitor 0:
x: 0 y: 0, scale: 1.0, rotation: normal, primary: no
associated physical monitors:
    HDMI-1 1920x1080@60

logical monitor 1:
x: 1080 y: 0, scale: 1.0, rotation: normal, primary: yes
associated physical monitors:
    eDP-1 1920x1080@59.987873077392578

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/Downloads/./gnome-randr.py", line 850, in <module>
    dc_iface.ApplyMonitorsConfig(config_info.serial,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in __call__
    return self._connection.call_blocking(self._named_service,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Logical monitors not adjacent

Does anyone has a solution? Either how to make gnome-randr work or another solution?
I also tried https://github.com/maxwellainatchi/gnome-randr-rust, it doesn't work either.
